# Is 'Regards by' a valid usage

Tags: grammaticality

Is 'Regards by' term correct when we end an e-mail.
I have seen ending mail using "With Regards, Warm Regards, Regards" but 'Regards by' seems somewhere wrong, please correct me if I am.

Comment: I've never seen "regards by". If neither have you, why are you even considering using it?

Comment: @RegDwigнt Well I had, that's the reason - I want to know whether its correct or incorrect usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common for people to mix up "regard" and "regards". The phrase "with regard" means "with attention to" or "with respect to". Think of it as a shortening of "regarding" like you see in e-mail subject lines (re: that raise you keep asking for).

The term "regards" is either the present tense of regard (Arun regards Reg as a thorough reader) or a colloquial way of saying "well wishes" ("give him my regards" or "best regards"). If you are writing a letter, it would be acceptable to say:

"Regards,

Arun"

So "Regards by" is a little weird in this context. Adding the "by" is like stating from a 3rd person perspective that the regards were authored by Arun; if you're Arun, and you're the one giving your regards at present, then just give them :-) That kind of reminds me when people begin speeches for class with "Today I'm going to be talking about ..." (it's a little superfluous; just speak to us! Don't give us meta data! We aren't web browsers or search engines).